# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, null, styles, getelementbyid

```
var n1 = document.getElementById("n1").style["background-color"];
```

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null*

so I try to change a table cell's background color but I get that. Not only that, but it says cannot READ, but it can actually WRITE to it (I mean I can change the background color the same way but I can't read its value).

CODE:

```
function checkDiagonal() {
    var n1 = document.getElementById("n1").style["background-color"];
    var n2 = document.getElementById("n2").style["background-color"];
    var n3 = document.getElementById("n3").style["background-color"];
    var n4 = document.getElementById("n4").style["background-color"];
    var n5 = document.getElementById("n5").style["background-color"];
    var n6 = document.getElementById("n6").style["background-color"];
    var n7 = document.getElementById("n7").style["background-color"];
    var n8 = document.getElementById("n8").style["background-color"];
    var n9 = document.getElementById("n9").style["background-color"];
    var n10 = document.getElementById("n10").style["background-color"];
    if (n1!=='000000' || n2!=='000000' || n3!=='000000' || n4!=='000000' || n5!=='000000' || n6!=='000000' || n7!=='000000' || n8!=='000000' || n9!=='000000' || n10!=='000000')
    {
        return;
    } else {
        var winner='Nobody';
        if (n1 == n2 && n2 == n3) { winner=n3; }    
        if (n1 == n4 && n4 == n7) { winner=n7; }    
        if (n1 == n5 && n5 == n9) { winner=n9; }    
        if (n2 == n5 && n5 == n8) { winner=n8; }    
        if (n3 == n5 && n5 == n7) { winner=n7; }    
        if (n3 == n6 && n6 == n9) { winner=n9; }    
        if (n4 == n5 && n5 == n6) { winner=n6; }    
        if (n7 == n8 && n8 == n9) { winner=n9; }
        if (winner=='Nobody') {
            document.getElementById("n1").style["background-color"]="FFFFFF";
            document.getElementById("n4").style["background-color"]="FFFFFF";
            document.getElementById("n7").style["background-color"]="FFFFFF";
            document.getElementById("n8").style["background-color"]="FFFFFF";
            document.getElementById("n9").style["background-color"]="FFFFFF";
        }
    }
}
var st = new playerTurnObj(); //Pointless to explain this, it has nothing to do
</script>
</head><body>
<table align="center" border=0>
<tr align="center"><td id="n1" style="background-color:000000" onclick="switchTurnGen(st); mark('n1'); checkDiagonal('n1');"></td><td id="n2" style="background-color:000000" onclick="switchTurnGen(st); mark('n2'); checkDiagonal('n2');"></td><td id="n3" style="background-color:000000" onclick="switchTurnGen(st); mark('n3'); checkDiagonal('n3');"></td></tr>
<tr align="center"><td id="n4" style="background-color:000000" onclick="switchTurnGen(st); mark('n4'); checkDiagonal('n4');"></td><td id="n5" style="background-color:000000" onclick="switchTurnGen(st); mark('n5'); checkDiagonal('n5');"></td><td id="n6" style="background-color:000000" onclick="switchTurnGen(st); mark('n6'); checkDiagonal('n6');"></td></tr>
<tr align="center"><td id="n7" style="background-color:000000" onclick="switchTurnGen(st); mark('n7'); checkDiagonal('n7');"></td><td id="n8" style="background-color:000000" onclick="switchTurnGen(st); mark('n8'); checkDiagonal('n8');"></td><td id="n9" style="background-color:000000" onclick="switchTurnGen(st); mark('n9'); checkDiagonal('n9');"></td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

**EDIT**: I found out the problem. the problem was at id n10, there are only ids until n9, so n10 obviously caused an error. Sorry for asking this then

Comment: show us your html code

Comment: does this work `document.getElementById("n1").style.backgroundColor`?

Comment: @androidavid — No. Cannot read property **'style'** of null

Comment: Try wrapping your code in `window.onload = function(){ /*code goes here*/ };` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var n1 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("n1"),null).backgroundColor;
```

It'll give you the color in rgb.

Comment: thanks, it worked. Though how can I get it in hexadecimal? and how does it work?

Comment: No, wait. the other thing worked too. I'll edit my post explaining what happend, and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*edit*

So, my first assumption was correct. In your edited code, there is clearly no element with `id="n10"`, however, you have this line of code

```
var n10 = document.getElementById("n10").style["background-color"];
```

which [jsFiddle will point to on error](http://jsfiddle.net/GNZHm/) when a number is clicked from the grid.

---

Answer from before edit

The problem is that there is no element with `id="n1"`. See this reproduction of your error here: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UTDEY/)

You should either target the right id, or if this code is executed before the element exists, then use `onload`

```
var n1;
window.onload = function(){ 
 n1 = document.getElementById("n1").style["background-color"]; 
};
```

Comment: Reason for downvote? Seems pretty obvious that the element wasn't present.

Comment: I dont know who downvoted, but it wasn't me, I upvoted anyway. Yes, I just noticed myself of this and posted it as an edit, then I read what you just said